# Combine nearby points into single point with average location in ArcGIS Pro

Tags: arcgis-pro, point, combine, average, aggregate

I've added GPS waypoints to my ArcGIS Pro map using the GPX to Feature conversion. However, some points are clearly "duplicates" of the same location because they are so close together. (Sometimes 3+ points appear to be for the same point of interest).

I've already used the **Near** tool to visualize in tabular form which points are <3m distance apart (< than my GPS unit's accuracy).

**Goal: I'd like to combine each set of points that are <3m apart into a single point represented by the average easting/northing values of each.**

What I've looked into:

- **Aggregate** doesn't seem appropriate since I have no polygon to "lump" the close-neighbors by.
- **Aggregate Points** also doesn't seem appropriate b/c I want to keep my features as points vs. converting to polygons.
- **Central Feature** also didn;t work for me since it picks one of the existing points, while I want to create a new point with avg Easting/Northing of selected points.

**How could I go about doing this?**  (I'm using ArcGIS Pro 2.8)

Comment: [Central feature](https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/latest/tool-reference/spatial-statistics/central-feature.htm)?

Comment: @Hornbydd thanks for the suggestion. I didn't know about that tool. However, it's not quite what I'm looking for. I'm hoping to create a *new* point that is located at the average easting/northing of all other points selected.

Answer (score 1):

The tool called [Mean Center (Spatial Statistics)]:

> Identifies the geographic center (or the center of concentration) for
> a set of features.